# Preventing video download by browser integrated download manager

Tags: php, video, download, video-streaming

I am using PHP to prevent downloading of video files played on my site. I use a PHP endpoint to hide the video file URL, I store a token in database for each play request, also I set a temporary password for each play request and store it in a session. I check the token and the password in the session with values stored in database. Also I check the user agent of the page requesting the video with the user agent of the PHP video player endpoint to be the same. I check the referrer page of the video player PHP to be from my site as well.

So far, I managed to prevent downloading the video by copying the video URL into the browser or into a download manager. But IDM Download Panel (a browser integrated download manager) still can download the video. I guess that's because it can fake it to be part of the browser and the open session and uses the same session, user agent, etc.

I wanted to know how can I prevent a download manager that is integrated into browser from downloading the video file.

One way is deleting the token from database, or mark it as "played" once the video play started. But if I do this, users will not be able to go forward and backwards on the video.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: No matter _what_ you do, ultimately, it's playing on the client machine so if someone really wants to capture the video they will and there's not much you can do about it...

Comment: @CD001 I know that. But I want to make it as hard as possible for the ordinary user.

Comment: @mehra use DRM: https://castlabs.com/resources/drm-comparison/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.